# Registration of custom int TypeConverter broken with Struts2 upgrade ( 2.1.6 --> 2.3.15 )

Tags: java, struts2

i have a java web application using struts2 (vers: 2.3.15) and I need to apply type convertion to a int fields.

that field can have the value "-", and i must change it to 0 using type conversion, but with the new version of struts2 when i send the form is returning to the form with the validator error without passing from the type conversion.

I wrote the following code:

```
package sistema.conversores;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTypeConverter;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrador
 */
public class IntegerConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {

    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
System.out.println("load");
        if (values.length != 1) {
            super.performFallbackConversion(context, values, toClass);
        }
System.out.println("conversion");
        final String numero = values[0];

        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(numero);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
        final NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");
System.out.println("lectura");
        if (o instanceof Integer) {
            return formatter.format(o);
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(o);
        }
    }
}
```

And append it to xwork-conversion.properties

```
# syntax: <type> = <converterClassName>
int = sistema.conversores.IntegerConverter
java.util.Date = sistema.conversores.DateConverter
```

But the int type conversion don't run on Struts 2.3.15, and this is working on struts 2.1.6

i need to upgrade version because of ONGL bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3580

How can I fix this?

Comment: Struts2 already contains `int` converter by default, what other converter do you need?

Comment: because the int converter by the default give back to form with a validation error if the value entered in the field is not a number and I want that field to display empty if no set. in struts 2.1.6 this work fine

Comment: Is your custom Date converter still working?

Comment: i tried it and doesn't work, maybe is something with another libraries. i will try delete all y use only struts libraries

Comment: My point was that you should verify that the configuration mechanism that you are using is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this issue, 
it was a problem with the struts.xml and the struts.properties on the WEB-INF

i do the following

1. delete the struts.properties from the web-inf, only the xml is requiered
2. delete all libreries from the previus version and copy and update the libraries

after doing this all type converter starting to working fine